# Swift store and retrieve array data using UserDefault

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

In my scenario, I need to store `array` values into `UserDefault` and retrieve the same data. The retrieve data need to load into the same array when the user opens again that particular `viewcontroller`.Below code what I am trying. I don't know how to `store` and `retrieve` below array output values into UserDefaults in a proper way. Please help me with this.

**Store Data Into Array**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let item = searching ? filteredData[indexPath.row] : membersData[indexPath.row]

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
                cell.accessoryType = .none

                // UnCheckmark cell JSON data Remove from array
                self.selectedRows = selectedRows.filter{$0 != indexPath.row}
                self.selectedValues.remove(item) // Here Data Removing Into Array

            } else {
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark

                // Checkmark selected data Insert into array
                self.selectedRows.append(indexPath.row) //select
                self.selectedValues.insert(item) // Here Data Storing Into Array
            }
        }        
    }
```

**Save array data into UserDefault**

```
@IBAction func doneAction(_ sender: Any) {

        // Selected Row Index Store
        UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedRows, forKey: "SelectedIndexes")
        // Here need to store Selected values
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

**Reload UserDefault Stored data into same array (viewDidLoad)**

```
    self.selectedRows = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "SelectedIndexes") as? [Int] ?? []
// Here how to retrieve SelectionValue and Load into `selectedValues` array
```

**Codable**

```
// MARK: - ListData
struct ListData: Codable, Hashable {
    let userid: String?
    let firstname, designation: String?
    let profileimage: String?
    var isSelected = false

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case userid, firstname, designation, profileimage
    }
}
```

**Array Data**

> SELECT VALUE:[ListData(userid: Optional("1"), firstname:
>   Optional(“abc”), designation: Optional(“English”), profileimage:
>   Optional("url")), ListData(userid:
>   Optional(“2”), firstname: Optional(“def”), designation:
>   Optional("Digital"), profileimage:
>   Optional("url"))] SELECT ROW:[0, 1]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201939/discussion-on-question-by-iosdev-swift-store-and-retrieve-array-data-using-userd).

Comment: @PGDev after search search result checkmark not working by above but without search checkmark working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store in UserDefault although it's not suggested.

```
var selectedValues: [Any] = [["id": 1, "name": "Adam"]]
selectedValues.append(["id": 2, "name": "Eve"])
UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedValues, forKey: "SelectedValues")
let result = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "SelectedValues") ?? []

print(result)


Output : [{
  id = 1;
  name = Adam;
}, {
  id = 2;
  name = Eve;
}]
```

Comment: Why `AnyObject`? All values are value type. And why `value(forKey`? There is `array(forKey`

Comment: @vadian yes you are right. I have updated the code, You can look and let me know if it valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save list in UserDefaults, you can only `Any` data type list in UserDefaults. First you should save your selected row in `Any` data type list.
**Step 1:** Declare list as `Any` data type and append selected row data in it.

```
var selectedValues: [Any]?
```

**Step 2:** Make a variable in separate class where all your UserDefaults save that store `Any` data type list in

```
//MARK: store selectedValues

private let KeySelectedValues = "KeySelectedIndexes"
fileprivate var _selectedValueList = [Any]()

var selectedValueList : [Any] {
    get {
        _selectedValueList = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: KeySelectedIndexes) as? [Any] ?? _selectedValueList
        return _selectedValueList
    }

    set {
        _selectedValueList = newValue
        UserDefaults.standard.set(_selectedValueList, forKey: KeySelectedIndexes)
    }
}
```

**Step 3:**  Save the list in UserDefaults like

```
classObj.selectedValueList = selectedValues
```

**Step 4:** To retrieve data list from UserDefaults

```
let _selectedValueList = classObj.selectedValueList   
guard let selectedValueList:[YourSelectedRowModel] = Mapper<YourSelectedRowModel>().mapArray(JSONArray: _selectedValueList as! [[String : Any]]) else {
     return
}
```

Comment: *You can only `Any` data type list in UserDefaults* That's wrong. You can save all property list compliant homogenous types as array in UserDefaults (`[String]`, `[Int]`, `[Double]`, `[Bool]`, `[Date]`, `[Data]`).

Comment: @vadian I said Any data type list. You can not save any other model type list.

Comment: What does *data type list* mean? The code shows an array. You can save `[Int]`  – which `selectedRows` actually represents – but your code will crash if you are going to save non-property list compliant types.

Comment: selectedRows is a list or array with data type a model that contain multiple type variables like int, string, bool etc. You can save same data type of array as [Int], [String] but not [YourModelType]. So I'm saying if you want to save model type list or array in UserDefault you can save with the help of my code.

Comment: No, `selectedRows` in the question is clearly `[Int]`.

Comment: yes, thanks @vadian I have edited my answer. I accepted it is not `selectedRows `, I replace 'selectedRows' with 'selectedValues'.